# Specify "other"

Tags: java, jcheckbox

I am working with GUIs on my java homework and I have to specify what other is within a JCheckBox. I have everything else finished except for this minor requirement. I'm not quite sure how to go about this, I've looked in my book and tried researching it online

---

Requirement:

A series of check boxes where the supervisor can choose which sports events their     residents are most interested in (basketball, hockey, swimming, football, soccer, tennis, wrestling, other). Next to the check box that says "other" should be a text box so the supervisor can specify what "other" means.

---

If you need any clarification let me know I'm new to posting here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Your code will look like :

JCheckBox chk_other = new JCheckBox("Other");
JTextField txt_other = new JTextField();
txt_other.setVisible(false);

    chk_other.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                txt_other.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ah so would that make the textbox dynamic and only be active when "other" is selected?

Comment: You need to make the visibility of the text box as false initially, and when you will click on the other check box, the visibility needs to be changed to true.

Comment: Also, make sure that the visibility of the text box needs to be made false again when you click another check box (if the visibility is true by using isVisible() method.

Answer (score 1):

Just have a text field that becomes visible (or keep it visible the whole time) when other is selected.  On the back end if other is selected read the value of the parameter sent from that text box.

Comment: Yeah I just dont know the syntax to add in a text box. 
"JCheckBox jcbOther= new JCheckBox("Other");"
creates the check box, but how to add the text box? and how do I have it display what was typed in the actionsPreformed window?
if(jcbOther.isSelected() )
      message += "\nOther is selected";

Comment: Can you implement an JTextField within a JCheckBox?

Comment: Why not put the JTextField after the JCheckBox? Your code will do the logical linking of the two, putting it after in the code would produce what you want would it not?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :D

> JTextField jtfOther = new JTextField(10);
>
> JCheckBox jcbOther= new JCheckBox("Other");

adds the textbox and check box

> if(jcbOther.isSelected() ) message += "\nOther: " + jtfOther.getText()
>   + " is selected";

displays it in the actionPerformed window